# Can we prove the existence of a non-measurable subset using an uncountable well-ordered subset without $\sf DC$?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Can we prove in $\sf ZF \ +$ “Every subset of $\mathbb R$ is Lebesgue measurable.” that $\aleph_1 \not \leq | \mathbb R|$?

I [know](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02760523) that if we also assume $\sf DC$, the claim holds, but I don’t know if it can be done without using choice at all, thank you.

Comment: DC is generally needed in order to make some sense of measure theory, otherwise weird things can happen. But, yes, that's a question I've wondered about before.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What kinds of things can happen?

Comment: Countable unions of countable sets could be uncountable in ways that make it impossible to define a measure properly, etc. (Granted, many of these significant failures imply there is no uncountable well-ordered set of reals, but it's still easier sometimes to just chuck it all out the window for the low, low price of DC.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I see, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this post, I show that the main consequences of countable choice regarding Lebesgue measure follow from (and are equivalent to) the assertion that the class of measurable sets is closed under countable union: https://mathoverflow.net/a/393162/109573

In particular, all of these properties of Lebesgue measure follow from the assertion $``$all sets of reals are measurable.$"$

A while ago, I went through Raisonnier's article and convinced myself that his arguments can all be carried out in this context. In particular, the Fubini argument that the null ideal is closed under well-ordered union can be carried out with an ad hoc verification of the relevant integration properties. I don't think there were any other subtleties that could cause a problem in the absence of choice.

Comment: Which Raisonnier's article did you read? Just curious.

Comment: The one linked in the question.

Comment: Oops, I did not carefully read the question. Thank you.